# Is there any difference between list.elementAt(n) and list[n]

Tags: dart

In Dart, is there any difference between accessing list elements using `elementAt` and the `[]` operator?

```
var sensors = ["ir", "ultrasound", "laser"];

void main() {
    print(sensors.elementAt(1));
    print(sensors[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.elementAt()` method is coming with the `Iterable` class. It works with all iterables, not only `Lists`.
Some iterables may have **more efficient** ways to find the element, so do Lists, using the bracket notation.

#### What do I mean by *more efficient*?

The bracket notation will call .elementAt() implicity. The bracket notation does not serve any additional meaning, only ease of use - as many would say, it's a "syntactical sugar". This is what I mean by efficiency. You can use it with less typing. I did not mean algorithmic efficiency, like finding the element faster in a large `List` or anything like that.

Also, Lists in Dart are similar to the so called "arrays" in many languages. These old-school languages use bracket notation to identify array elements. So the bracket notation is also a tradition and serves the purpose of getting started easily with Dart, when you come from a background of Java or C# ... etc.

Comment: So is the bracket notation more efficient than the .elementAt(). It isn't just calling it internally?

Comment: The bracket notation will call .elementAt() implicity. The bracket notation does not serve any additional meaning, only ease of use - as many would say, it's a "syntactical sugar". Also, since Lists in Dart are equivalent to arrays in many languages, which use bracket notation to identify array elements. So the bracket notation is also a tradition and serves the purpose of getting started easily with Dart, when you come from a background of Java or C# ... etc.

Comment: It's not "syntactic sugar". See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference, try to run [this](https://gist.github.com/ivanesi/afac1ca148ecd370cb65ef9bdd99d398) with and without `dart2native` compilation

for my MacBook it will be:

```
mb:mobile ivan$ dart test.dart 
iterable 448
list 19
list bracket 36
mb:mobile ivan$ dart2native test.dart -o zzz
mb:mobile ivan$ ./zzz 
iterable 2
list 1
list bracket 0
```

If i decrease `elementsCount` to `10000000`:

```
mb:mobile ivan$ dart test.dart 
iterable 484
list 19
list bracket 9
mb:mobile ivan$ dart2native test.dart -o zzz
mb:mobile ivan$ ./zzz 
iterable 2
list 1
list bracket 0
```

and for `elementsCount = 100000000`:

```
mb:mobile ivan$ dart2native test.dart -o zzz
mb:mobile ivan$ ./zzz 
iterable 13
list 32
list bracket 1
```